# two powerbooks cannot access one wifi point at the same time

Tags: wireless-networking, powerbook

This is for a friend of mine. She says

> Please tell me why we have such
>   destabilized connections when we log
>   both Powerbooks on at once. When one
>   laptop's logged in, and the other
>   opens his/hers too, it can take ten
>   minutes of restarting/rebooting to get
>   us both on, and sometimes we just
>   can't have both of us at once. Please
>   for the love of cheese and all that is
>   holy, what do we need to do?

Comment: BTW, it is password protected...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly point, but how is you WLAN set up? Does your router assign IP addresses or are they fixed? The reason I ask is that if you used migration assistant fro one Powerbook to the other `nd you used fixed IP addresses you might have the same IP addresss for both laptops.
Just a thought.
Anyway for more help, I think we need more details
1) Exactly which computers?
2) Running which operating system(s)?
3) What router?
4) What configuration?